# Installed package is still missing

Tags: errors, latexmk

I need MnSymbol.sty in a template I use. During the build I got this:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `MnSymbol.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:
! Emergency stop.
<read *>
```

So I downloaded the MnSymbol from CPAN (http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/mnsymbol.zip) (I don't have a direct internet access) and unzipped the files into one of these folders:

```
$ texhash
texhash: Updating /etc/texmf/ls-R...
texhash: Updating /usr/share/texmf-dist/ls-R...
texhash: Updating /usr/share/texmf-site/ls-R...
texhash: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R...
texhash: Done.
```

I took the last one: `/var/lib/texmf/` and copied the content of the archive. After it I rerun `texhash`:

```
$ unzip mnsymbol.zip -d ~/texmf
$ cd texmf/mnsymbol/
$ cp -R * /var/lib/texmf
$ texhash
```

The package is still missing

What is my mistake?

I am working on Cygwin with TexLive.

Comment: What *complete path* did you use? Note that `/var/lib/texmf` is definitely a bad place for a package file.

Comment: @egreg I updated my question

Comment: Sorry, no, that ZIP file is not meant for direct unzipping in one of the TeX trees. There is a README file in the ZIP file that explains what you should do.

Comment: Arf ! So I did exactly what it says in the `README` and I have the same issue `MnSymbol.sty` not found